# html multi steps form

Tags: html, forms

Hey i have a question is that better make multiple-steps form with multiple form tags or i can do it with one single form and just separate with divs ?

```
      <!-- example 1 -->
      <form name="first-step" id="first-step" action="" method="">
          <input type="radio" name="">
          <input type="susbmit" name="continue" value="continue">

      </form>

      <form name="second-step" id="second-step" method="" action="">
        <input type="text" name="street">
        <input type="submit" name="submit">
      </form>

      <form name="third-step" id="third-step" method="" action="">
        <input type="text" name="">
        <input type="submit" name="submit">
      </form>

     <!-- example 2 ************* -->
      <form  action="" method="">

        <div id="first-step">
         <input type="radio" name="">
         <input type="susbmit" name="continue" value="continue">
        </div>

        <div id="second-step">
         <input type="text" name="street">
         <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
       </div>

       <div id="third-step">
        <input type="text" name="">
        <input type="submit" name="submit">
       </div>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the best is separating only divs, since all data refer to the same form. At least you want to have save data step by step.

In the auxiliary forms, you can place buttons that hide the current div and shows the next, and on the last div, you introduce the normal submit field.

Comment: okay and what if i need in each step one submit button ? is it still same ?

Comment: I do not believe that is the best option, although you can still do: when the form is submitted, you check if it's the last step, if not, you can stop the submit event, and then show the next step.